# Convert html to checkbox razor view

Tags: html, razor, checkbox

I have the following checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="seaMode" name="transportMode" value="Origin Service" />
<label for="seaMode" data-label="Sea">Sea</label>
```

However I am using razor view for that binding the view to the model:

```
@foreach (var val in Model.TransportList)
{
    @Html.Label(val.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @for = label })
    <i class=@val.Image></i>
    @Html.CheckBox(label, false, new { value = @val.Text, name = "transportMode" })
}
```

Right now, it is returning it as below:

```
<label for="SEAMode">SEA</label>
<i class="icon-sea"></i>
<input id="SEAMode" name="SEAMode" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="SEAMode" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Any one good with html can please help me to add the correct class and attribute so as to render the html as the 1st one?

For info, val.Value has SEA and val.Text = 1 and so on.

Comment: So you just want the class name and data-attribute added to `@Html.CheckBox(label, false, new { value = @val.Text, name = "transportMode" })`?

Comment: @M12Bennett :  Yes

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add a class and data attributes then this should do it:

```
@Html.CheckBox(label, false, new { value = @val.Text, name = "transportMode", @class = "myCheckBox", data_label = "my data label value" })
```

Let me know if this helps.